# HOSTAPD / WPA_SUPPLICNAT on Windows

Tags: windows, p2p, wpa-supplicant, hostapd

On Linux/Ubuntu we have **HOSTAPD and WPA Supplicant** which can make wireless NIC card either **access point or hotspot or p2p** (wifi direct).

Is there any way to perform the same **on Windows**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use WPA_Supplicant on windows. Per the [readme](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/README-Windows.txt). This should help you get pointed in the right direction.

> ## wpa_supplicant for Windows
>
> Copyright (c) 2003-2009, Jouni Malinen  and contributors All
>   Rights Reserved.
>
> This program is licensed under the BSD license (the one with
>   advertisement clause removed).
>
> wpa_supplicant has support for being used as a WPA/WPA2/IEEE 802.1X
>   Supplicant on Windows. The current port requires that WinPcap
>   (http://winpcap.polito.it/) is installed for accessing packets and the
>   driver interface. Both release versions 3.0 and 3.1 are supported.
>
> The current port is still somewhat experimental. It has been tested
>   mainly on Windows XP (SP2) with limited set of NDIS drivers. In
>   addition, the current version has been reported to work with Windows
>   2000.
>
> All security modes have been verified to work (at least complete
>   authentication and successfully ping a wired host):
>   - plaintext
>   - static WEP / open system authentication
>   - static WEP / shared key authentication
>   - IEEE 802.1X with dynamic WEP keys
>   - WPA-PSK, TKIP, CCMP, TKIP+CCMP
>   - WPA-EAP, TKIP, CCMP, TKIP+CCMP
>   - WPA2-PSK, TKIP, CCMP, TKIP+CCMP
>   - WPA2-EAP, TKIP, CCMP, TKIP+CCMP
>
> ### Building wpa_supplicant with mingw
>
> The default build setup for wpa_supplicant is to use MinGW and
>   cross-compiling from Linux to MinGW/Windows. It should also be
>   possible to build this under Windows using the MinGW tools, but that
>   is not tested nor supported and is likely to require some changes to
>   the Makefile unless cygwin is used.
>
> ### Using wpa_supplicant for Windows
>
> wpa_supplicant, wpa_cli, and wpa_gui behave more or less identically
>   to Linux version, so instructions in README and example
>   wpa_supplicant.conf should be applicable for most parts. In addition,
>   there is another version of wpa_supplicant, wpasvc.exe, which can be
>   used as a Windows service and which reads its configuration from
>   registry instead of text file.
>
> When using access points in "hidden SSID" mode, ap_scan=2 mode need to
>   be used (see wpa_supplicant.conf for more information).
>
> Windows NDIS/WinPcap uses quite long interface names, so some care
>   will be needed when starting wpa_supplicant. Alternatively, the
>   adapter description can be used as the interface name which may be
>   easier since it is usually in more human-readable format.
>   win_if_list.exe can be used to find out the proper interface name.